# adapt plot code to make a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

`[1] 0.09733344 0.17540020 0.14168188 0.54093074 0.78151039 0.28068527
 [7] 1.96164429 0.33743328 0.05200734 0.09103039 0.28842044 0.09240131
[13] 0.09143535 0.38142022 0.11700952`

from which I did bayesian inference and made a plot with the following code

```
f_theta<-function(theta,Data){
(theta^length(Data) )*exp(-theta*sum(Data))}
theta<-seq(1,20,length=100)
a=b=0.001
plot(theta,dgamma(theta,a,b),type="l",col="red",
ylim=c(0,2),tck=-0.01,cex.lab=0.8,cex.axis=0.8)
lines(theta,dgamma(theta,length(Data)+a,sum(Data)+b),col="green",lty=1)
lines(theta,f_theta(theta,Data=Data),lty=1,col="blue")
legend('topright',legend=c("Prior","Post","Likelihood")
 ,col=c("red","green","blue","purple"),lty=1,bty="n",cex=0.8)
```

But I've seen the following graph

[image]

which has code

```
# ggplot2 examples
library(ggplot2) 

# create factors with value labels 
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
labels=c("Automatic","Manual")) 
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

# Kernel density plots for mpg
# grouped by number of gears (indicated by color)
qplot(mpg, data=mtcars, geom="density", fill=gear, alpha=I(.5), 
main="Distribution of Gas Milage", xlab="Miles Per Gallon", 
ylab="Density")
```

but I'm not quite familiar with ggplot library and graphs and I would like some help in order to adapt my code and make a graph similar to last one.

Comment: See if you can narrow this down to the core of the question: you have some data (you could post the output of your analysis), you want to plot distributions, and you're not sure what bits of the example `ggplot` code need to be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot()` assumes that your data are in a particular format (sometimes called "long", but the author of `ggplot()` dislikes that description), so let's start by putting them into that format:

```
Data2 = data.frame(
    theta = rep(theta, 3),
    WhichDistribution = c(rep("Prior",length(theta)), rep("Post",length(theta)), rep("Likelihood",length(theta))),
    Density = c(dgamma(theta,a,b), dgamma(theta,length(Data)+a,sum(Data)+b), f_theta(theta,Data=Data))
)
```

Then we can construct a `ggplot()` command. `ggplot()` needs data, aesthetics, and a geometry. Your data will be the data frame just constructed. The aesthetics refer generally to how the qualities of the data will impact the graph (what is on axes, what determines groups, etc.), and the geometry is the kind of plot (not a great wording, sorry).

```
ggplot(Data2, aes(x=theta, y=Density, group=WhichDistribution, color=WhichDistribution, fill=WhichDistribution))+
    # position="identity" in order to not stack the densities
    geom_area(alpha=.2, position="identity") +
    # gets rid of the title on the legend
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    # make the horizontal axis label pretty
    scale_x_continuous(expression(theta))
```

You can change `alpha` to adjust transparency. If you want the horizontal axis to not go all the way to 20, change it in `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
ggplot(Data2, aes(x=theta, y=Density, group=WhichDistribution, color=WhichDistribution, fill=WhichDistribution))+
    # position="identity" in order to not stack the densities
    geom_area(alpha=.2, position="identity") +
    # gets rid of the title on the legend
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    # make the horizontal axis label pretty
    scale_x_continuous(expression(theta), limits=c(0,7))
```

[image]

`qplot()` is a quick plotting function that seems to mostly get in the way for people trying to learn the `ggplot()` language, so you might want to avoid it.